# SQL - Comando para classificação geral

Tags: mysql, sql

Olá, eu tenho um tabela similar a:

```
user_id server_id record date_record    
123 333 3 2020-05-10
343 343 4 2020-05-12
133 333 5 2020-05-15
123 333 10 2020-06-10
343 343 12 2020-05-12
123 333 5 2020-05-15
123 433 50 2020-05-10
```

Nessa tabela, podem se repetir registros pelo user_id.

Eu preciso de comando SQL que:
- Selecione os melhores 25 pontuadores(os 25 melhores record), ignorando dados repetidos. 
Então no caso do user_id 123, o comando deveria apenas retornar o `maior registro(maior record)`, **ignorando** os registros anteriores com **menor record**.

O que eu tenho:

```
SELECT user_id, server_id, user_record FROM user_ranking ORDER BY user_record DESC LIMIT 100;
```

O resultado que eu desejo:(com base no exemplo)

```
user_id server_id record date_record  


123 433 50 2020-05-10
343 343 12 2020-05-12
133 333 5 2020-05-15
```

Comment: *"maior registro(maior record)"* aqui já está a sua resposta, use isso com `group by` e terá o resultado desejado. Se tiver dúvidas, tem várias perguntas sobre `group by` aqui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso, agrupe os valores usando `group by`, para eliminar os repetidos, assim por exemplo:

```
SELECT user_id, 
       server_id, 
       max(user_record) user_record,
       max(date_record) date_record
  FROM user_ranking 
GROUP BY user_id, 
         server_id
ORDER BY user_record DESC 
LIMIT 100;
```

Note que, todos os campos usando no `select` ou no `order by` precisam estar no `group by` ou usando alguma função de agregação no `select`, como é o caso do `max(user_record)`.

Veja funcionando no [http://www.sqlfiddle.com/](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d253e/2)

Comment: Ainda recebo dados duplicados  :(

Comment: Com algumas alterações eu consegui fazer o que queira, o caminho era este! Muito obrigado Ricardo.